# How reliable is the MaxLength property of the TextBox-Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox, maxlength

The TextBox control offers a [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) property, which allows the insertable text into that TextBox be clientside limited to the specified amount of chars.

**My questions**:

- Is this property only client-side and
  therefore browser-pedendent?
- Can I rely on the fact, that the
  Text property contains no text longer than
  MaxLength is set (only for the
  DisplayModes named in the MSDN
  article) or do I manually have to
  perform a TextBox.Text.SubString(0,
  DesiredMaxLength)
  ?
- How does all this
  behave with disabled java-script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not depend on javascript but that does not make it safe.

Anyone can still post a request using javascript (XmlHttpRequest for example) or just craft a request to send more data than the max-length specification. It's a good way to stop a normal user from over populating a field but it is something you need to double check on the server anyway.

Comment: Meaning the TextBox-Control does not server-side security to limit the MaxLength Property? If I understand you correctly, you are telling me, that with "normal" usage from within my webapp I can rely that a normal user can't bypass the specified maxlength?

Comment: The text box will not check on the server side AFAIK. And I am saying that for a normal user not trying to do anything wrong it would work but that it not safe to rely on it.

Comment: I was pretty disturbed how easily one could get around the MaxLength limitation if they really wanted to. The way I went around fixing this(instead of attaching a million validators) was to extend the TextBox class and override the Text Property. In the getter, if the MaxLength value is greater than 0, I trim the value to the MaxLength value.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I rely on the fact, that the Text
>   property contains no text longer than
>   MaxLength ?

No. Consider it a user-friendliness feature. You will have(as always) re-check on the server. And maybe also check in JavaScript, depending on what its for.