# How do i limit the number of characters a user can type in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want to limit the number of characters a user can type in a textbox (say no more than 100 characters). How can i achieve that?

Comment: Just remember to check/limit the number of characters at server side too, in case someone sends more than 100 chars.

Comment: Niklas. thank you , i will...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) property.

This results in HTML something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" />
```

However, it's worth mentioning that this is only validated on the client-side and is easy to bypass. You should also validate it on the server-side, by checking the `Length` of the `TextBox.Text` property.

Comment: i applied maxlength.. the user wont be able to send more than 100 characters cause the textbox wont let him.. so why to check on the server side?

Comment: That's been answered to some degree here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416242/how-reliable-is-the-maxlength-property-of-the-textbox-control
Basically it's easy for a malicious user to alter the data before it arrives at your server. You can do it with the Web Developer Toolbar add-on for FireFox and others.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`MaxLength` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Value1" MaxLength="100" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript would be your best bet in case you have **Multiline** textbox

```
function IsMaxLength(obj, MaxLen)
{
  return (obj.value.length <= MaxLen);
}
```

and attach this to the `Textbox`

```
onkeypress="return IsMaxLength(this, 100);"
```

else for the normal one as the others have suggested *setting `Maxlength` would suffice*

Comment: V4Vendetta, thanks for this - just what I was looking for too, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the MaxLength property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MaxLength` property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="zoneTextBox" runat="server" Height="23px" 
             onkeypress="CallToButton();"
             Width="89px" MaxLength="1"></asp:TextBox>
```